# Accessibility service is not allowing to releasing app memory

Tags: android, memory, accessibility

I am using one Normal service and one Accessibility service in my app

If I am not enabling accessibility service for my app it releases all its memory soon after I close my app and endup with only 2.7mb while another service runs.

But once after I enable Accessibility services it holds all my app memory and not releasing it even after a long time.

For test purpose I have used an empty accessibility service class which has nothing in it but still it is holding my app memory for almost 30mb.

Please help me on this. Your  suggestions are much appreciated
Below are the codes that I have used

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
....
  <service android:name="com.test.service.MyAccessibilityService"
      android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
....
</application>
```

### MyAccessibilityService.java

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
...
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

      System.out.println("My event: "+event.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {

     AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
     info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
     info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
     info.notificationTimeout = 100;
     setServiceInfo(info);
    }

...
}
```

It is as simple as you see above, I have coded nothing in the accessibility service class but still it is not allowing to release my app memory when accessibility is enabled from settings -> accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Put your permission outside the application tag

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
 <application>....</application>
```

Comment: Sorry Ram, this does not help me. Still it holding app memory

Answer (score 0):

As of now for this issue I am killing my process to release the held memory.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

This works fine without any  issues but it is not recommended.

Comment: The framework will suspend the activity when the system is low on memory, you don't need to manually kill the process.